# Search and Replace File and Folder name

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I have the following file structure :

```
.
├── data
│   └── test_sample.txt
└── demo_test
    ├── data.php
    ├── index_test.php
    └── Test.php
```

I want to replace 'test' with 'demo'. The final file structure will be

```
.
├── data
│   └── demo_sample.txt
└── demo_demo
    ├── data.php
    ├── index_demo.php
    └── Test.php
```

How can I achieve this via a shell script.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: using sed command but that only goes inside the file , it does not change file name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do it in two phases:

1. Rename the directories
2. Rename the files

```
cd yourDir
find . -type d -name "*test*" | while read f; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/test/demo/'); done
find . -type f -name "*test*" | while read f; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/test/demo/'); done
```

Find lists all the files and directories that matches "test" we then process the ouput of the command line by line